# display an alternate text on mouseover for a table entry

Tags: html

I have a table one of whose column displays the employee id of the employees. i need to display there names when mouse moves on it . 
can anyone help me with that??

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`alt` is an attribute, not a tag, and it is not for mouse over, it shows up when image is not loaded, try using `title` instead

So try this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td title="Employee Name">1</td>
    <td title="Another Employee Name">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```